# multiple task to run when they time out

Tags: java, timertask

How to run multiple timer tasks in java that will be timed out in 20secs for example,  but all of them have started at different time, but still they have run after 20 secs after created.  I am planning to receive a lot of task that i need to keep for that period of time and then trigger another event once its seconds are gone.

There can be multiple task running at the same time.
I have seen http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/overview/quick-start but i want to know if there is another way to accomplish what i want.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way of doing it using the java.utils package:

```
    public class Main {
        private static final int delayMilliseconds = 20000;  // 20 seconds
        private static Timer timer;

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
            System.out.println("START");
            // Create a Timer
            timer = new Timer();
            doTask();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            doTask();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            doTask();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            doTask();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("END");
        }

        public static final void doTask(){
            System.out.println("Started at: " + Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            System.out.println("Perform your task here");
            // Create new task
            TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Run the "timeout finished" function here.
                    System.out.println("Timed out! " + Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                }
            };

            // Schedule a task for in 20 seconds in the future.
            timer.schedule(task, delayMilliseconds);
        }
    }
```

If you've used Java 8 before (or would like to use it), you could try using this code instead:

```
    public class Main {
        private static final int delayMilliseconds = 20000;  // 20 seconds
        private static Timer timer;

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
            System.out.println("START");
            // Create a Timer
            timer = new Timer();
            doTask(() -> System.out.println("Task 1"));
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            doTask(() -> System.out.println("Task 2, starting a second later"));
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            doTask(() -> System.out.println("Task 3, starting a second later"));
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            doTask(() -> System.out.println("Task 4, starting a second later"));
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("END");
        }

        public static final void doTask(Runnable function) throws Exception{
            System.out.println("Started at: " + Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            // Run the function here
            function.run();
            // Create new task
            TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Run the "timeout finished" function here.
                    System.out.println("Timed out! " + Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                }
            };

            // Schedule a task for in 20 seconds in the future.
            timer.schedule(task, delayMilliseconds);
        }
    }
```

The second method makes it so you can pass a function to the `doTask()` function. Look at  [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)  for more info on the Timer class and look at  [this link](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Lambda-QuickStart/index.html)  for more info on lambdas in java 8. :)